# I am new, trying to roll 3d6, rerolling 1's, and put them into a list. I cant seem to get 3 "new" values in the list. The numbers just keep adding up

Tags: python, dice, rolling-computation

```
import random

my_stats = []

stat = 0

while len(my_stats) < 3:
    for i in range(1,4):                # generates a num (d6) but no 1's
        number = (random.randint(1, 6))
        while number == 1:
            number = (random.randint(1, 6))
        else:
            stat += number          # sums the 3 rolls into stat

    my_stats.append(stat)

print(my_stats)
```

I am not sure how to get 3 distinct entries in my list, just keeps adding up.

Comment: You should put a bit more explanation in the body of the question and come up with a short title of what the problem is, instead of writing the whole thing in the title. Include an example output, describe what's wrong with it and what you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code currently rolls a die 3 times, adding the results if the roll is not 1, otherwise rerolling the die pointlessly (as the value is never used). The summed value is then appended to a list and you repeat the process, but without resetting the sum to 0 first. So it contains at least 2 errors (as ignoring the 1 and not using the reroll  doesn't appear to be what you want)

I think this is what you were after:

```
import random

my_stats = []

stat = 0

while len(my_stats) < 3:
    # you'd want to restart the count every time
    stat = 0
    # you'll need to keep track of the number of good rolls, can roll any number of 1's
    good_rolls = 0
    while good_rolls < 3:
        number = (random.randint(1, 6))
        if number != 1:
            stat += number          # sums the 3 rolls into stat
            good_rolls += 1

    my_stats.append(stat)

print(my_stats)
```

Answer (score 0):

You never reset `stat`.

Try moving its initialization into the loop, e.g.

```py
while len(my_stats) < 3:
    stat = 0
    for i in range(1,4):
        # ...
```